# Failed to build an existing application due to lack of jcenter certificate - blocked by gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jcenter

I tried to build an andruid application using latest andruid studio 
Seems that gradle is blocked due to lack of jcenter certificate in local machine certstore. My colleguee succeed to build it on his machine so the problem is in the configuration and not the application code

Configuration :  andruid studio 3.0.1, gradle 3.0.0 ?, windows 7

I also tried to workaround ssl handshake by replacing jcenter() in build.gradle with

```
 maven {
            url  "http://jcenter.bintray.com"
        }
```

but it didn't solve the problem

My build.gradle below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [assemble]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'PDA'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > Connect to repo.jfrog.org:80 [repo.jfrog.org/52.72.224.151, repo.jfrog.org/34.204.33.255] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin v.**3.x.x**

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

**is not** in `jcenter`.
You have to use the google maven repo.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using Android Studio 3 and gradle v.4.x you can use the `google()` shortcut

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ... 
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides as @GabrieleMariotti alreay said, that library will not be found at JCenter, you should not get `Connection timed out: connect` but a message that the library was not found.

`Connection timed out: connect` hints, that you cannot access that URL from your machine. My best guess is that you have to use some Proxy to access this URL that properly configured for your colleague, but not for you.